# Enlarge div on mouse over

Tags: javascript, html

I want to enlarge a div when I move over another div. It's working fine if I am setting the new dimension of the div like this:

```
function enlarge(i) {
     if(jsmolwindow[i]===true){
         divname="jsmolwindow"+i;
         document.getElementById(divname).style.height='350px';
         document.getElementById(divname).style.width='350px';
     }
}
```

But I would like to enlarge by 30px or 30% not set a definite size. I am not succeeding in doing so.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please, show the div with its styling. If not, it's impossible to know how to modify it in the best possible way

Comment: How do you specify 30px or 30% (Your not working code)?

Comment: That's what I don't know. I tried document.getElementById(divname).style.height=document.getElementById(divname).style.height+"30px" but that's won't works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use CSS3 :hover pseudo-selector? e.g `div:hover div.2(//code}`.

There is a css property `transform: scale(1.3)` which will enlarge the div by 30% each time without any funky maths invloved ;)

Comment: But that will change text-size as well, etc. that doesn't  change the width/height only.

Comment: I am changing the size of a div on hovering on another div that's why I am not using hover.

Comment: @Laetis but you still can use hover to change the size of another div. e.g. `#div1:hover #div2 { .. code .. }`

Answer (score 0):

would something like this work for you? you can use jquery to do the `transforms` in css. i used classes `.enlargeMe` to target which elements to make bigger, and `.div1` as my target hover over div to trigger the enlarging of the other divs.

(ps. `.hover()` is finicky in browsers sometimes if the mouse moves too fast over an element. thats why i chose to use `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()`)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.div1').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $('.enlargeMe').css({
      '-webkit-transform' : 'scale(1.3)',
      '-moz-transform'    : 'scale(1.3)',
      '-ms-transform'     : 'scale(1.3)',
      '-o-transform'      : 'scale(1.3)',
      'transform'         : 'scale(1.3)',
    });
  });
  $('.div1').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('.enlargeMe').css({
      '-webkit-transform' : 'scale(1)',
      '-moz-transform'    : 'scale(1)',
      '-ms-transform'     : 'scale(1)',
      '-o-transform'      : 'scale(1)',
      'transform'         : 'scale(1)',
    });
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin-right: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br/><br/>
<div class="div1">This is div 1</div>
<div class="div2 enlargeMe">This is div 2</div>
<div class="div3 enlargeMe">This is div 3</div>
```

all that `-webkit` stuff is for cross browsers. if you know which browsers you are catering to, you can eliminate some of that code. in its simplest form, it is:

```
.css('transform', 'scale(1.3)');
```

Comment: @Shikkediel ahh, yes i missed that >< thanks for bringing that up. i suppose i'll leave it up here anyways. if OP likes the functionality, OP can convert to vanilla js. thanks again!